# gem install datamapper error

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, datamapper

I'm trying to install datamapper and I'm getting this error:

```
Whirlwind:Desktop AGreen$ gem install data_mapper
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/AGreen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/.gitignore
```

I also tried to install it this way:

```
Whirlwind:Desktop AGreen$ gem install datamapper
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/AGreen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/.gitignore
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permission issue to me.

To check:

```
ls -l ~/.rvm
```

Should all belong to you.

To fix:

```
sudo chown -R AGreen /Users/AGreen/.rvm
```

You may also consider chown'ing your whole home directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on linux, you'll need to prefix your command with sudo.

Try

```
sudo gem install data_mapper
```

Comment: I'm on a mac. I tried that too, for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: yes. I just installed the dm-postgres-adapter gem. everything worked perfectly

Comment: It strongly depends if RVM is installed in userspace or as root. As far as i see `/Users/AGreen/.rvm`, it's definitely a userspace installation.